# Microsoft visual studio emulator for Android setup failed: the hash value is not correct

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

need your help immensely.

I am currently using visual studio community 2015 with update 3. I Tried installing Microsoft visual studio emulator for Android, i got a response that vs_platform_api19.msi is missing. i downloaded the file and installed it manually. I ran the setup again, the response was **Setup Failed!, Microsoft visual studio emulator for Android API 19 platform, The hash value is incorrect.** I have uninstalled vs_platform_api19.msi using Orca.exe and deleted all the folders in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio Emulator for Android yet the problem still persists.

[image]